# On cancel click not able to set previous data in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created dynamic fields from JSON data, and I am successfully rendering on UI

- Initially all the fields are disabled.
- Once I click on edit I am making particular row editable which is working fine
- On click of cancel what I want to do is make the fields disabled again  and it should take the previous (initial value)

**Issue**

When I click on cancel I am setting the initial data aging but it is not taking, I am using `react-form-hook` for form validation, there we have `reset()` function but that too is not working.

**What I am doing is**

Getting data from main component and setting it to some state variable like below

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (li) {
      setdisplayData(li);
      setCancelData(li);
    }
  }, [li]);
```

- Now using `displayData` to render the elements

  On click of `Edit` I am doing this

  const Edit = () => {
  setdisabled(false);
  };

and on click of cancel I am doing below

```
const cancel = () => {
    setdisabled(true); //disbaled true
    console.log(cancelData);
    setdisplayData(cancelData); setting my main data back to previous one
    reset(); // tried this reset of react hook form but it did not work
  };
```

I am using `defaultValue` so that when I click on Edit the field should allow me to edit.

[Here is my full working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-tdd-w2bil?file=/src/component.js:522-647)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue I changed up your code to use `value` instead of `defaultValue`. Additionally added an `onChange` event handler which updates the `displayData` state whenever `<input>` changes value. Moreover, you do not need the `cancelData` state at all since the `li` prop has the original values.

Now when the `onClick` for the cancel button is fired, it resets the value of `displayData` state to whatever `li` originally was. Here is the modified code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function component({ li, index }) {
  const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(true);
  const [displayData, setdisplayData] = useState(null);
  const { register, reset, errors, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (li) {
      setdisplayData(li);
    }
  }, [li]);

  const Edit = () => {
    setdisabled(false);
  };

  const cancel = () => {
    setdisabled(true);
    console.log(li);
    // Reset displayData value to li
    setdisplayData(li);
    reset();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {disabled ? (
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={Edit}>
            Edit
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={cancel}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
      <br></br>

      {displayData !== null && (
        <>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="fname">first name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="fname"
              disabled={disabled}
              value={displayData.name}
              // Update displayData.name everytime value changes
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                setdisplayData((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: value }))
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="lname">last name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lname"
              disabled={disabled}
              value={displayData.lname}
              // Update displayData.lname everytime value changes
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                setdisplayData((prev) => ({ ...prev, lname: value }))
              }
            />
          </div>
        </>
      )}

      <hr></hr>
    </div>
  );
}

export default component;
```

Hope this helps. Drop a comment if it's still not clear :)

Comment: Have you got the issue why it is not working with `defaultValue` ?

Comment: The `defaultValue` attribute simply stores the initial value of the input tag. Whereas `value` stores the current value of the input tag. Traditionally you would use the `defaultValue` and `value` attributes to compare what has changed in the input value. In your react code, you have the default value in the `li` prop so its not necessary here to set `defaultValue`.

Comment: Hey could you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703295/how-to-achieve-hash-routing-in-react-with-scrollspy

I have been stuck here for so long.